# Is it possible to send keys or component events to a 3rd party swing application

Tags: java, swing, automation

I have a situation where I need to push text to 3 text boxes of a small one-form Swing application and then press a button (in other words, automation).  The application is not written by me and is available only as a jar file.

The situation is similar to that of test frameworks that do UI test automation. (If it were a Windows / .NET / SWT application, something like Project White framework would be useful. )

Is such a thing is possible?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you have access to the buttons or text boxes? if you do, you can set them in your code. and I know for a JButton, you can create an event by `doClick()` method.

Answer (score 1):

You can fix the swing application on the desktop, and get the absolute positions of text boxes and the button. Then, use the [quick macro](http://www.qmacro.com) to send the right events of keyboard and mouse to the swing application.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. Will try it out if there are no other robust / reliable mechanisms available.